# i have two table in which i have to store data but i can't able to store data in second table

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-radiogroup

i have to two table "OWNER" and "USER" on selecting the first radio button it  save the data on user table and on selecting second radio button data will be save on owner table

database helper class which contain the function to create the user table and owner table and insertdataUse  insertdataOwner funtion to insert the data in table

here is my singup page in which we have two function adddatauser to user and adddataowner to

public class SinGUP extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Databasehelper myDB;
EditText et_name,et_pnumber,et_email,et_password;
private  static Button btnsignup;
String name,pnumber,email,password;
RadioButton r1,r2;
RadioGroup rg;
public int x;
TextView loginbtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sin_gup);



    myDB = new Databasehelper(this);
    et_name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_pname);
    et_pnumber=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_pnumber);
    et_password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_password);
    et_email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_email1);
    r1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton_Owner);
    r2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton_user);
    loginbtn=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_login);

    //TypeOfUser();
    loginbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i= new Intent(SinGUP.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    btnsignup=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_singup);
    btnsignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            singup();


        }
    });


}





public void singup()
{
    initializes();

            if(!Validate())
            {
                Toast.makeText(SinGUP.this,"sigup can't be done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

    else {

            rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
            int selectOptId = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            r1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectOptId);
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), r1.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (r1.getText() == "radioButton_user")
                Adddatauser();
            if (r1.getText() == "radioButton_owner")
                AdddataOwner();


            }
}




public void initializes()

{
    name=et_name.getText().toString().trim();
    pnumber=et_pnumber.getText().toString().trim();
    email=et_email.getText().toString().trim();
    password=et_password.getText().toString().trim();

}

public boolean Validate()

{
    boolean valid=true;

    if(name.isEmpty()||name.length()<7){
        et_name.setError("please enter the valid name");
        valid=false;}
    if(pnumber.isEmpty()||pnumber.length()<10){
        et_pnumber.setError("please enter the valid phone number");
        valid=false;}
    if(password.isEmpty()||password.length()<7){
        et_password.setError(" password length 8");
        valid=false;}
    if(email.isEmpty()||!isValidEmail(email)){
        et_name.setError("please enter the valid email");
        valid=false;}
    return valid;
}
```

public boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
        String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"+"[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

`Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    return matcher.matches();
}



    //function to add  owner detail
public void AdddataOwner(){

                    boolean inserData = myDB.insertdataOwner(name, pnumber, password, email);

                    //  boolean insertDataU = myDB.insertdataUser(name.

                    getText().toString(), pnumber.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString(), email.getText().toString());

                    if (inserData == true)
                        Toast.makeText(SinGUP.this, "data inserted  owner", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    else

                        Toast.makeText(SinGUP.this, "data  canot be inserted owner", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

//function to add  user detail
public void Adddatauser(){

                    boolean insertDataU = myDB.insertdataUser(name, pnumber, password, email);





                    if (insertDataU==true)
                        Toast.makeText(SinGUP.this, "data inserted user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    else

                        Toast.makeText(SinGUP.this, "data  canot be inserted user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change below condition

```
if (r1.getText() == "radioButton_user")
    Adddatauser();
if (r1.getText() == "radioButton_owner")
    AdddataOwner();
```

to

```
if (r1.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("radioButton_user")) {
    Adddatauser();
} else if (r1.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("radioButton_owner")) {
    AdddataOwner();
}
```

Comment: it is showing error

Comment: which error is shown?

Comment: sry thats was my faluts

Comment: sir can u see this question    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42125328/attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-java-util-arraylist-filename-databasehelper